# how do I make text visible over any picture using JES?

Tags: python, jes

Im trying to use the addText function in JES that can take any picture as an argument and change the color of the text I am adding accordingly. I am not sure how to approach this. Obviously my approach is completely wrong in the middle, Im just not sure how to get the average color of a certain range of pixels.

```
def enhancedAddText(pic):
  textPic=duplicatePicture(pic)
  startX=int(getWidth(pic)/3)
  startY=int(getHeight(pic)/3)
  for x in range(startX, startX+100):
    for y in range(startY, startY+10):
      pixel = getPixel(textPic, x, y)
      r=getRed(pixel)
      g=getGreen(pixel)
      b=getBlue(pixel)
      average=(r+b+g)/3

  textColor=    
  addText(textPic, startX, startY, 'Hope this worked', textColor)
  show(textPic)
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: wow sorry Im new and that destroyed the formatting, one min

Comment: Please add it to your question.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, hope that helped